# Understanding of Buffer index in compute shader

Tags: compute-shader

compute shader script:

```
#pragma kernel CSMain
RWStructuredBuffer<int> result;
 
[numthreads(8, 8, 8)]
void CSMain(int id : SV_DispatchThreadID )
{
    result[id] = id;
}
```

c# script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ForTesting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ComputeShader compute;
 
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        ComputeBuffer resultBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(8*8*8, sizeof(int));
     
        var kernel = compute.FindKernel("CSMain");
        compute.SetBuffer(kernel, "result", resultBuffer);
        compute.Dispatch(kernel,1,1,1);
 
        int[] result = new int[8 * 8 * 8];
        resultBuffer.GetData(result);
   
        resultBuffer.Release();
    }
}
```

These are testing code for what value is in a result.
I don't understand result[id] = id; line.

Exactly, `result[id]`. Accessing with index to buffer.

And while google, I saw a post saying that the shader function is executed as many as the number of threads.

Then in above case, cause numthreads(8, 8, 8) and Dispatch(kernel, 1, 1, 1), Does CSMain function run 8 * 8 * 8 * 1 * 1 * 1 times?

Comment: `int id : SV_DispatchThreadID` should be `int3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID` sorry I didn't read it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Firstly `result[id] = id;` is not type safe.</strike>  `id` has three `int` components but the index to `result` and the value of `result` is just an int. So what's really happening is just the first component is being used i.e. `result[id.x] = id.x;`

Edit: I should have said `int id : SV_DispatchThreadID` is not type safe, it should be `uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID` as `SV_DispatchThreadID` has three components.

You can access the second and third elements by `id.y` and `id.z`.

---

You can think of the compute shader as a for loop

```cs
void kernel(int[3] id)
{
    ...
}

List<int[3]> ids;

for (var id : ids)
    kernel(id);
```

except each call to the kernel is executed in parallel not sequentially.

---

You should read the documentation here to understand how `List<int[3]> ids;` i.e. `SV_DispatchThreadID` are calculated

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/sm5-attributes-numthreads
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-dispatch

In your specific case:

```cs
var iota = Enumerable.Range(0, 8);
List<int[3]> ids = cartesian_product(iota, iota, iota);
```

where ids has size/length `8*8*8`;

Comment: Then, Is Kernel function loop 8 * 8 * 8 times with different id(cartesian result)?
But still I don't understand about ``result(RWStructuredBuffer)`` variable,  I only know indexing about list like.
Is Buffer type similar with list?

Comment: `RWStructuredBuffer<int>` is just an array of ints (you index with an int) i.e. `List<int>` in c#. The other version is `RWTexture2D<int>` is like a multi dimensional array (you index it with `int2` which has two int components).

Comment: Ah thanks.I have a last question.Then how can I know the buffers length?For indexing have to know that.

Comment: @y202100 haha. You can't. You know at creation, and you have to keep track of how long each buffer when you call ` compute.SetBuffer()`. You can call the same compute shader on buffers of different lengths

Comment: You mean buffer parameter in ``SetBuffer(kernelIndex, nameID, buffer)`` define the length of StructuredBuffer? Right??

Comment: No. You pass in a buffer you have already created here `ComputeBuffer resultBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(8*8*8, sizeof(int));` with length `8*8*8,`

Comment: @y202100 `result[id.x + 8 * id.y + 8 * 8 * id.z] = ...; Would be the natural way to index the result

Comment: Very thank you for your kindness. You save my life. Have a nice day!!